# How to upload and compare lists?

Tags: python, list, import, set

I have two lists, one with 76 species and the other with 150 species. I put them all in one by one, but I need to know the way to do it faster by uploading the lists from a .txt file in Python. And then I want the program to be able to manipulate them like I did here, and save it in the same folder. I just started learning Python and it is my first computer language and am really confused. Any help at all is extremely appreciated.

```
list_A = ["I. apiculata", "I. arguta", "I. arguta (alba)", "I. arguta (blue)", "I. balfourii", "I. bicolor", "I. bombqsinn", "I. breartii", "I. burtonii", "I. campanulata", "I. capensis", "I. catatii", "I. cathcartii (spotted)", "I. cathcartii (yellow)", "I. caudex", "I. ceratophora", "I. cinnabarina", "I. clavicular", "I. cymbifera", "I. eriosperma", "I. fischeri", "I. flaccida", "I. gardneriana", "I. gomphophylla", "I. grandis", "I. grandulifera", "I. hians", "I. hochstetteri", "I. hoehnelli ex cherangani", "I. hoehnelli var teliki", "I. honskonpenia", "I. iceilli", "I. insignesis", "I. irvingii", "I. kilimanjari", "I. laurantii", "I. mackeyana spp. claeri", "I. marianae", "I. mengtzeana", "I. mengtzeana (red dragon)", "I. mirabilis (pinkish)", "I. mirabilis (yellow)", "I. mishmensis", "I. mukeyanaz", "I. namchabarwensis", "I. nana", "I. niamniamensis", "I. noli-tangeri", "I. omeiana", "I. oxyanthura", "I. pallida", "I. parasitica", "I. parishii", "I. paecidentata", "I. phengklaii", "I. phuluangensis", "I. platypetala", "I. platypetala (magenta)", "I. psychadelphoides", "I. puberula", "I. quinchengensis", "I. repens", "I. rhombifolia", "I. rothii", "I. ruilensis", "I. salpinx", "I. scabrida", "I. shirensis", "I. sichuan (gold)", "I. sodenii", "I. tinctoria", "I. tuberosa", "I. tubulosa", "I. usambarensis", "I. xanthina"]
list_B = ["I. acehensis", "I. amoena", "I. amphorata", "I. andohahelae", "I. andringitrensis", "I. angulata", "I. anovensis", "I. apalophylla", "I. aquatilis", "I. arguta", "I. aureliana", "I. auricoma", "I. balansae", "I. balsamina", "I. barbata", "I. baroni", "I. begoniifolia", "I. bequaertii", "I. bicornuta", "I. blinii", "I. bombycina", "I. brachycentra", "I. burtonii", "I. campanulata", "I. capensis", "I. chekiangensis", "I. chinensis", "I. chishuiensis", "I. chiulungensis", "I. chlorosepala", "I. claerii", "I. claviger", "I. columbaria", "I. conchibracteata", "I. congolensis", "I. corchorifolia", "I. cordata", "I. cuspidata", "I. cyanantha", "I. cyathifora", "I. cymbifera", "I. davidii", "I. delavayi", "I. desmantha", "I. drepanophora", "I. duclouxii", "I. eubotrya", "I. faberi", "I. falcifer", "I. firmula", "I. fischeri", "I. fissicornis", "I. flanaganae", "I. forrestii", "I. fragicolor", "I. fuchsoides", "I. furcata", "I. gibbosa", "I. gongshanensis", "I. harai", "I. henslowiana", "I. hians", "I. hoehnelii", "I. holocentra", "I. hongkongensis", "I. hunanensis", "I. imbecilla", "I. inaperta", "I. keilii", "I. kerriae", "I. kilimanjari", "I. lateristachys", "I. laxiflora", "I. lecomtei", "I. leptocaulon", "I. leschenaultii", "I. levingei", "I. lobulifera", "I. macrovexilla", "I. malipoensis", "I. manaharensis", "I. margaritifera", "I. mengtzeana", "I. meruensis", "I. microstachys", "I. miniata", "I. monticola", "I. morsei", "I. napoensis", "I. neglecta", "I. niamniamensis", "I. noli-tangere", "I. nubigena", "I. nyimana", "I. obesa", "I. omeiana", "I. oxyanthera", "I. parasitica", "I. parviflora", "I. percrenata", "I. piufanensis", "I. pingxiangensis", "I. platychlaena", "I. platypetala", "I. platysepala", "I. poculifer", "I. principis", "I. pritzelii", "I. pseudoviola", "I. pterosepala", "I. purpurea", "I. racemosa", "I. radiata", "I. rectangula", "I. rothii", "I. rubrostriata", "I. sambiranensis", "I. scabrida", "I. scullyi", "I. scutisepala", "I. siculifer", "I. sodenii", "I. soulieana", "I. spathulata", "I. stenosepala", "I. stuhlmannii", "I. subabortiva", "I. sulcata", "I. sunkoshiensis", "I. taronensis", "I. tayemonii", "I. teitensis", "I. textorii", "I. tienmushanica", "I. tinctoria", "I. tortisepala", "I. trichosepala", "I. tuberaculata", "I. tuberosa", "I. tubulosa", "I. uliginosa", "I. urticifolia", "I. usambarensis", "I. vilersi", "I. walleriana", "I. wenshanensis", "I. wilsonii", "I. xanthina", "I. yaoshanensis", "I. zenkeri"]
print(set(list_A) & set(list_B))

print(set(list_A) - (set(list_A) & set(list_B)))

print(set(list_B) - (set(list_A) & set(list_B)))
```

Comment: "and am really confused" <- You and me both, man.

Comment: Do you want to read lists from a file?

Comment: What do you mean by "upload" them?

Comment: yes. I need to know where the two files with each list should be located in order to pull them up. I also have to be able to pull up both lists in the program from a different computer

Comment: I mean upload from a text file. In which each species name is on a different line. And make that into a list in Python

Answer (score 0):

For put in a one list without repetition you can use:

```
combined_list = list(set(list_A + list_B))
```

Comment: What question is this an answer to?

Comment: *Any help at all is extremely appreciated.* part I guess, even if not a question; still a humane reaction to me :)